# SharePoint Classic view via URL parameter

Tags: sharepoint-online, url, parameter, classic-experience, classic

Is it possible to force SharePoint to use Classic experience with URL parameters?

(For example https://companyname.sharepoint.com/Lists/ListName/AllItems.aspx?ClassicExperience=True)

There is a Bookmark list that we uses on a daily basis, but some of our custom developed pages are not properly showing in the Modern experience, and our colleges have to click on "Change back to old SharePoint" link every single time.

There is a link that leads to the Classic SharePoint:

```
<a class="LeftNav-notificationLink" role="menuitem" data-bind="attr: { href: $data.url, target: $data.openInNewTab &amp;&amp; $data.openInNewTab() ? '_blank' : null, tabindex: $component.isLeftNavVisible() ? 0: -1, 'aria-label': $data.altText }, visible: !$data.show || $data.show(), click: $component.onClick.bind($component), automation: $data.automationId, automationType: 'Link'" href="#" tabindex="0" aria-label="Kattintson vagy nyomja le az enter billentyűt, ha vissza szeretne térni a klasszikus SharePointra" data-automationtype="Link">
<span class="LeftNav-linkText" data-bind="text: $data.text">Vissza a klasszikus SharePointra</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Have you considered reverting the entire list back to classic experience in List Settings -> Advanced?

Comment: @Jake Some of us are using the New Experience, but admins who have elevated permissions are struggling with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JavaScript bookmarklet which will open the list and then perform a click on the link after some milliseconds.

```
javascript:window.open("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/Lists/MyListName");setTimeout(()=>{document.getElementById('WhateverLinkID').click();},500);
```